# Codeigniter htaccess and base_url

Tags: php, codeigniter

I install codeigniter and start to write some code on it.First i want to remove index.php and make some research about it.I remove it with a small htaccess code below,

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /pasaj/index.php/$1 [L]
```

and then set my base_url in config.php as,

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/pasaj/';
```

and then i decided to use base_url in form's actions

and wrote it like that(please look at action)

```
  <form method="post" id="formSubmit" name="fSubmit" action=<?php base_url(); ?>"kayit/kayitOnay/">
```

but it did not work

and prints url like that 
[image]

what i did all is not working

and i suspect from my htaccess file.I removed it. i use it for removing index.php in codeigniter default.

and set my new
base url like that necessarily

```
http://localhost/pasaj/index.php/
```

and do not change anything above form code

and it works.

Now, i want to still use this htaccess file in order to remove index.php but when  htaccess file exists my base_url works wrongly . What might be the changes in htaccess file ?

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /pasaj/
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

My htaccess files on a local server looks like this:

For a Zend Framework web:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

For a CodeIgniter web:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /pasaj/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
RewriteRule .* - [E=REMOTE_USER:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
```

Comment: added another example in my answer, still no go?

Answer (score 0):

This is my standard htaccess file.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    #Removes access to the system folder by users.
    #Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
    #previously this would not have been possible.
    #'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #When your application folder isn't in the system folder
    #This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
    #Submitted by: Fabdrol
    #Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    #request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

You may need to alter the rewrite base.

Answer (score 0):

To remove index.php from url you can try the following.

```
Open config.php from system/application/config directory and replace
$config['index_page'] = “index.php” by $config['index_page'] = “”

Create a “.htaccess” file in the root of CodeIgniter directory and add the following lines.

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]

In some case the default setting for uri_protocol does not work properly. To solve this problem just replace
$config['uri_protocol'] = “AUTO” by $config['uri_protocol'] = “REQUEST_URI” from system/application/config/config.php
```

Comment: can you explain this link if possible...RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]