# Codeigniter - urls

Tags: php, codeigniter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Codeigniter htaccess and base_url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9512741/codeigniter-htaccess-and-base-url)

I really dont understand codeigniter's url system.

There is a problem with base_url() function when i use it in views.

first of all,

my base url as declared in config.php like that

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/pasaj/';
```

and i want to use it in my view like that,

```
<form method="POST" action="<?php echo base_url() . "giris/main_page"?>" name="flogin" autocomplete="off">
```

but it prints url like that :

[image]

and nothing happens

what's the reason ?

Comment: Haven't you already asked this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9512741/codeigniter-htaccess-and-base-url

Answer (score 0):

You have syntax errors:

```
<form method="POST" action="<?php echo base_url() . "giris/main_page"; ?>" name="flogin" autocomplete="off">
```

You should indicate the ending of the statement with a semicolon (`;`), also, have a space between the last statement and the closing `?>` PHP tag.

Comment: That actually won't produce a syntax error - believe it or not. It's not an issue with syntax, whatever the issue is.

Comment: http//localhost/pasaj/giris still prints like that OMG